# How to create a table in an iframe jquery execCommand?

Tags: java, jquery, execcommand

I am trying to create a table inside an iframe using execCommand but it is not working. It just displays "null"

```
    $(insertTableBtn).click(function() {
        iframeDocument.execCommand('insertHTML', false, '<table><tr><td></td></tr></table>');
    });
```

Comment: did you check the answer?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention which browsers you have the problem with and there is no HTML code to check, so here is a working version:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<iframe id="ifr1" src="about:blank">
</iframe>

<button id="btn1">click</button>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('#ifr1').contents().find('html').html('<body contenteditable="true"></body>');
});
$('#btn1').click(function() {
    $('#ifr1').contents()[0].execCommand('insertHTML', false, '<table border="1"><tr><td>123</td></tr></table>');
});
</script>
```

You can check the jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/3c5Lwmeq/

> Note that the `insertHTML` is **NOT** compatible with Internet Exploere.